# Is it insecure to use an IV based on the key?

Tags: passwords, cryptography, aes, md5

If I feed AES an IV generated by MD5 using the key, will it cause a security risk? I understand that MD5 can be cracked in a sadly short amount of time, but will that effect the integrity of the cipher? The only weakness I see is that the hash can be used to find the key; but isn't it basically impossible to find the IV of a cipher using just the ciphertext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes. Using an initialization vector derived from the key is a security risk no matter what hashing algorithm you use. You should always use a cryptographically secure random number generator to create IV's.

A big problem with deriving an IV using a hashing algorithm is that the hash will always be the same for any given key.

An IV must never be used multiple times with same key. The point of an IV is to provide uniqueness to a message and prevent it from being encrypted into the same cyphertext multiple times. [Here](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/70059609995/crypto-noobs-1-initialization-vectors) is a post which gives a nice example of how an attacker could take advantage of this.

IV's are sent along side the encrypted message in the clear. This is fine, because they are not supposed to be a secret. The receiver needs the IV to properly decrypt the message. Sending the hashed key as the IV means that anyone who receives your message will see the hashed key. It is thus very possible for an attacker to discover the key via a rainbow table or even brute force.